# Fake counterexample to If every closed and bounded subset of a metric space M is compact, does it follow that M is complete?

Tags: real-analysis

I am just starting to self studying Pugh's Real Analysis (note although this is an easy question, it is not homework. I am in HS and out of classes, and I wanted to learn some stuff) I found the question answered here: [If every closed and bounded subset of a metric space $M$ is compact, does it follow that $M$ is complete?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1625771/if-every-closed-and-bounded-subset-of-a-metric-space-m-is-compact-does-it-fol), but I am just trying to understand why my counterexample does not work.

Counterexample: consider $M = \mathbf{R} \setminus \{0\}$. Every closed and bounded subset is compact, because any closed interval $[a,b]$ where $a,b > 0$ or $a,b < 0$ is compact. However, $M$ is not complete; for example take $a_n = \frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: Notice that $[-1,0)\cup (0,1]$ is closed and bounded in $M$, but it is not compact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to math.SE!

Consider the interval $I=\left(0,1\right]$. Clearly $I$ is bounded.

The complement of $I$ in $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ is $I^c = (-\infty,0)\cup(1,\infty)$. The set $I^c$ contains an open ball around each and every point, and is therefore open. Thus, by definition its complement $I$ is closed.

However, $I$ is not compact, since e.g. sequence $n \mapsto \frac{1}{n}$ has no convergent subsequence.

Answer (score 1):

In your proposed counterexample, the set of points of your sequence $a_n = 1/n$ is a closed and bounded subset, but it is not compact. So the hypothesis is not satisfied.

Why is this subset closed? Remember that we are working in the space of real numbers excluding zero now. Any *non-zero* real number has a neighborhood that misses all points of the sequence $a_n$.